# Adobe Stratus Drawbacks

Tags: adobe, soundcloud-stratus, lccs

Am wondering if there are any drawbacks of using Adobe Stratus. Since it is only P2P, when will there be a case where P2P can't be used? On the site it says something like when UDP packets are blocked. How often is that? Say a thousand people use the service, approximately what percentage would not be able to use it?

Also, is it possible to port a Stratus app to AFCS/LCCS without any modification?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a pretty global audience, i had about 20% failing the initial test with cc.rtmfp.net . then a number of those who passed couldn't make direct connections to some users, although they could with others.

i wouldn't use stratus by itself for anything where reliability matters. use fms until red5 adds support for rtmfp

Answer (score 2):

About half on average are not able to talk directly. Depending on service provider, organization if any, country, continent, weather, extraterrestrial presence etc :-)

Comment: not the right answer. but accepting it anyways as this question is too old now.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking at this for a client who is developing a peer to peer video conferencing app.
In his experience about 10%+ of people out of a small group surveyed had UDP blocked, and therefore were unable to use Adobe Stratus to make connections and LTMFP